# Hosting Sitefinity project on staging server

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, sitefinity

I am hosting sitefinity project on staging server on which already multiple projects are hosted.

The url created on staging is : `www.testing.info/sitefinityproject`
When I click on any link on the page, then it redirects to

```
http://www.testing.info/about-us
```

But it should be : `http://www.testing.info/sitefinityproject/about-us`

I cannot find links to pages and images while running the website.

I cannot host the project on root i.e. as a new website.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not hard-coded the links, they should resolve automatically when you run the site as a virtual folder (as opposed to a web site). Maybe try to republish the base page template and see if this helps.